# Create NSPredicate that passes an object to an instance method

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have created an NSManagedObject called TItem. To that object, I've added a helper instance method like the following:

```
- (BOOL) isItemForUser:(TUser *)user;
```

isItemForUser compares various properties in the TUser object to itself and returns a BOOL based on the results of the comparison.

I want to create a predicate that will be able to pass a TUser object to that method so that I can find all TItem objects that would return YES with a given object passed. In essence, I want to do something like the following:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isItemForUser:%@ == YES",self.user];
```

The above syntax is obviously not correct, but I am looking for a something in the same spirit. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would explore doing whatever comparisons done in your `isItemForUser` method in the predicate instead.  Perhaps simplifying your data model to make that comparison easier?  For instance, adding some new attribute that maps to a user and is calculated when the object is created.  That way, the comparison is very simple.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. It does break some of the encapsulation I was looking for. This method compares the user's gender and age to it's own properties. (It basically answers the question: "Is this TItem appropriate for a Male over 30?", for example.) So I wanted the TItem itself to determine that, using this method. If I am to understand you, you suggest just exposing the `forGender` and `forAge` properties of the TItem and then build a compound predicate that creates the same logical expression that `isItemForUser` currently evaluates? Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

`FUNCTION` is what you're looking for:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FUNCTION(SELF, 'isItemForUser:', %@) == YES", self.user]
```

Two things to note, however:

1. `isItemForUser:` will have to return an `NSNumber`, not a `BOOL`
2. I'm 99.9999% sure this will not work as part of a fetch request's predicate